# Для списка целых чисел вычислить произведение первого, третьего и шестого положительных элементов и определить их номера в массиве

Tags: python

мне нужно чтобы в моей программе если нет тех самых положительных элементов то произведение элементов было 0,как это сделать?

```
def is_num(num):
    try:
        int(num)
        return True
    except:
        return False
arr = input("Введите список:")
arr = [num for num in arr.split() if is_num(num)]
N = len(arr)
i = 1
j = 1 
for i in range(N):
        if int(arr[i]) > 0:
                if j == 1:
                        i1 = i
                elif j == 3:
                        i3 = i
                elif j == 6:
                        i6 = i
                        break
                j += 1
        i += 1
        if int(arr[i]) < 0: 
            print("Произведение: 0")
if i6 > 0:
        print("Индексы положительных элементов:", i1, i3, i6)
        mult = int(arr[i1]) * int(arr[i3]) * int(arr[i6])
        print("Произведение:",mult)
else:   
        print("Произведение: 0")
```

Comment: Ни один из данных вам ранее ответов не подошёл или вы принципиально игнорируете правила ресурса и не отмечаете решения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
i1 = -1
i3 = -1
i6 = -1
for i in range(N):
...
mult = 0
if i6 > 0:
    print("Индексы положительных элементов:", i1, i3, i6)
    mult = int(arr[i1]) * int(arr[i3]) * int(arr[i6])
print("Произведение: ", mult)
```

Comment: у меня выскакивает сообщение об ошибке
if i6 > 0:
 NameError: name 'i6' is not defined

Comment: @Noob_Prog я присоединяюсь к вопросу SergeyGornostaev-a

Comment: Спасибо,за решение проблемы,а теперь к вашему вопросу. Я решаю разные проблемы по моей задаче,во всех вопросах я был удовлетворён,но вы как я понял подумали,что я задаю один и тот же вопрос поэтому если вы были введены в заблуждение и SergeyGornostaev приношу публичные извинения

Comment: @Noob_Prog Извинения приняты ). В дополнение к ним, пройдитесь, пожалуйста, по Вашим вопросам и отметьте подходящие ответы щелкнув по знаку "галочка" слева от ответа.

Comment: @Noob_Prog мы так не подумали. Просто когда вам дают ответ, решающий вашу проблему, [его надо решением отметить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Пожалуйста, потратьте 5 минут на просмотр [видео об основных механиках ресурса](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpTqzVGPLQY).